# Is mtime the begin time or the end time of the modification process

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is mtime updated when the modification process begins(open and write the file) or when the modification process ends(close the file )?

I found something at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478622/xfs-how-to-not-modify-mtime-when-writing-to-file).

`See man 2 stat for the semantics of mtime and ctime. 
In practice, the mtime and ctime will be updated in the in-memory copy of the inode and flushed out to disk asynchronously.`

I think the inode maybe be flushed more than once. If it is true.
Does it mean that the mtime  maybe updated more than once during the modification process?

Comment: It is updated with every`write`.

Comment: @n.m. Really? Could you give me some reference? Thanks

Comment: Just write a simple program that does a write and a flush every second. A bash script will do. Watch the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, every modification happens at a specific moment in time. The `mtime` is the time of the most recent such event.

If you want, you can think of a large write to the file as if it is broken into a series of individual writes of one byte (or bit, if you want!) each. The one-byte writes each occur instantaneously. So after the large write which takes a lot of time, the modification time should reflect the time when the last portion of the large write was done, that is, the end of the large write.

That's the regular writes (`write()`, `pwrite()`, `writev()`, etc...) It's not as cleear what should happen when a file is mapped into memory (using `mmap()`) and one of the memory addresses associated with the file mapping is updated. But in this case the standard has the answer. From Linux's `mmap()` manpage: "The  st_ctime  and  st_mtime  field  for a file mapped with PROT_WRITE and MAP_SHARED will be updated after a write to the mapped region, and before a subsequent msync(2) with the MS_SYNC or MS_ASYNC flag, if one occurs."

Opening a file doesn't count as a modification, by the way (even if you open the file for writing). Closing the file doesn't count as a modification either. Only actually writing to it does.